# Como mudar image em UIImageView igual a Galeria de Fotos?

Tags: objective-c, imagem

Cenário:

Carregar algumas imagens em um `NSArray` e mostrá-las em um `UIImageView` como é feito na galeria de fotos. Mas sem as opções de editar. Somente visualizar e mudar para o lado usando o swipe gesture.

Fiz uma código manualmente, mas não obtive o resultado final desejado.

Código que fiz:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){


    // Array para salvar imagens
    NSArray* imagens;

    //Imagens
    UIImage* img1, *img2, *img3;

    // ScrollView que fará a mudança
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Pegando as imagens
    img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"acai11.jpg"];
    img2  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gloria4.jpg"];
    img3  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gloria5.jpg"];

    // Alocando cada uma em uma posição no array
    imagens = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1,img2,img3, nil];

    // Pegando as dimensões de scrollView e passando para tamanhoPagina
    CGSize tamanhoPagina = scrollView.frame.size; 
    NSUInteger pagina = 0;

    // Iniciando e posicionando uma imagem dentro do ScrollView
    for (int i = 0; i < [imagens count]; i++)

    {

        // Criando um UIImgageView
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        // Passando o tamanho do scrollView para imagView, para que a imagem tenha o mesmo tamanho que o ScrollView
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 300,  scrollView.frame.size.height);
        imgView.image = [imagens objectAtIndex:i];
        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];

        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(tamanhoPagina.width * pagina ++ + 10, 0, tamanhoPagina.width - 20, tamanhoPagina.height);

    }

     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( scrollView.frame.size.width * imagens.count,  scrollView.frame.size.height);



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Abaixo irei listar as fotos do resultado final que desejo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que exista opções nativas para essa tarefa, e que não seja complexa ou difícil de implementar.

Qualquer dúvida com a questão basta comentar que posso adicionar mais informações ou fornecer detalhes da dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi bem fácil!!! Bastei fazer a seguinte implementação:

1 - Inicie um projeto no Xcode, Simples Aplicação com Storyboard.
2 - Depois vá ao `storyboard` e adicione um `UIScrollView` a tela e crie a sua propriedade no arquivo `ViewController.h`

Depois no arquivo `ViewController.m` insira o seguinte código:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    CGSize pageSize;
    NSUInteger page;
    NSArray* imagens;
    UIImageView *imgView;

    // Array para salvar imagens


    //Imagens
    UIImage* img1, *img2, *img3;

    // ScrollView que fará a mudança
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView1;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // Permite a imagem seguinte ser parada no meio da tela, como se fosse uma paginação.
    scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;

    // Pegando as imagens
    img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"acai11.jpg"];
    img2  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gloria4.jpg"];
    img3  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gloria5.jpg"];

    // Alocando cada uma em uma posição no array
    imagens = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1,img2,img3, nil];

    // scrollView1 é o IBOutlet para sua UIScrollView
    // Então pegamos o tamanho dela, as dimensões, e salvamos no pageSize
   pageSize = scrollView1.frame.size; 
   page = 0;


    // Iniciando e posicionando uma imagem dentro do ScrollView
    for (int i = 0; i < [imagens count]; i++)

    {

        // Criando um UIImgageView
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        // Passando o tamanho do scrollView para imagView, para que a imagem tenha o mesmo  
        // tamanho que o ScrollView
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 300,  scrollView1.frame.size.height);

        // Carregamos a imagem equivalente no índex " i " para imgView
        imgView.image = [imagens objectAtIndex:i];

        // Adicionamos a imagem como uma subview do scrollView1
        [scrollView1 addSubview:imgView];

        // Aqui calculamos o posicionamento das imagens com base em seu tamanho para que  
        // fique corretamente lado a lado
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 10, 0, pageSize.width - 20, pageSize.height);

}

     scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake( scrollView1.frame.size.width * imagens.count,  scrollView1.frame.size.height);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Espero ter ajudado!!

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas opções para você utilizar.

Exemplo: https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Caso queira implementar você mesmo, lhe indico alguns tutoriais:

http://blog.mobinius.com/image-gallery-photo-gallery-tutorial-for-ios-applications/

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Ambos os tutoriais são bem didáticos e fáceis de implementar.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado @Gian, vou conferir e trago um retorno!!

Comment: Bom @Gian, eu dei uma olhada, mas eles explicam muito além do que quero. No app que estou fazendo não preciso mostrar mosaico das outras imagens, somente mostrar um UIViewController e realizar a troca delas, de maneira animada, usando Gesture.

Comment: @TiagoAmaral, eu lhe apresentei estas opções para você ter uma base de como poderia fazer, não que fosse necessário implementar toda a galeria. Foi mais apresentar-lhe os principios "básicos" para lhe ajudar a fazer o que você precisa. Os meios para chegar onde você quer são varios. deixo aqui um link mais específico e dedicado ao que você deseja fazer:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-photo-gallery-with-uigesturerecognizer--mobile-8480

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez por trazer esses links, que realmente estão ajudando, e estou vendo aqui outros tutoriais explicando como implementar algo como eu quero. 
 Mas vou manter a questão em aberto ainda, caso alguém mais consiga fazer/encontrar um snap de código mostrando a implementação, ou pelo menos alguma que mostre um apontamento mais preciso. 

 Mas de qualquer forma, agradeço o esforço e o esclarecimento.

Comment: Bom eu consegui fazer um código que faz quase oque preciso, so preciso fazer um get center para melhorar a transição.

Comment: Vou colocar o novo código ai em cima. @Gian, dá uma olhada se você entende um pouco de Objective-C.

Obrigado

Comment: Este `getCenter` seria o centro da tela do dispositivo para centralizar a imagem?

Comment: sim! Precisaria fazer aquele efeito de pichar a imagem para o meio quando a próxima ja tivesse aparecendo... vc tem iPhone? já sabe do que estou falando?

Comment: Não tenho iPhone, mas trabalho com iOS, acredito que entendi mais ou menos o que você deseja fazer. Para isso basta fazer alguns cálculos que é fácil de obter.

Comment: Sim estou vendo e testando algumas medidas aqui, mas ta faltando algo... pq pelo que vi ele altera levemente a velocidade da passagem da imagem...

Comment: O centro da tela por exemplo você pode apenas dividir por 2 a largura e a altura. caso queira centralizar pode: origemX = (larguraTela / 2) - (larguraImagem / 2) ai você ajusta a altura

Comment: Ele tem uma espécie de animação easy-in e easy-out na transição

Comment: Acho que o easy-in e o easy-out é ligado ao zoom de imagens.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer, e é bem simples!! 
Amanha postarei a resposta, pois só posso responder minha própria pergunta depois de 2 dias. E foi bem mais fácil do que pensei!!!